# objective-c code to right pad a NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, padding

Can someone give a code example of how to right pad an NSString in objective-c please?

For example want these strings:

```
Testing 123 Long String
Hello World
Short
```

if right padded to a column width of say 12: and then a sting "XXX" is added to the end of each, it would give:

```
Testing 123 xxx
Hello World xxx
Short       xxx
```

That is a 2nd column would like up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adam is on the right track, but not quite there. You *do* want to use +stringWithFormat:, but not quite as he suggested. If you want to pad "someString" to (say) a minimum of 12 characters, you'd use a width specifier as part of the format. Since you want the result to be left-justified, you need to precede the width specifier with a minus:

```
NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-12@", someString];
```

Or, if you wanted the result to be *exactly* 12 characters, you can use both minimum and maximum width specifiers:

```
NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-12.12@", someString];
```

Comment: thanks - I think when I reviewing doco I may have assumed the formatting strings you have used were for decimals only, but if they work for strings this is great

Comment: NSString *someString = @"123456789012345678";  
    NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-30@", someString];  
    NSLog(@"%@", someString);  
    NSLog(@"%@", padded);  As I understand the discussion the code above should give a right padded version of someString. However, it prints out the same string two times. Am I missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately, I also find that the %@ formatter doesn't add spaces, per Johannes' comment.

Comment: I noticed that using `UTF8String` with an additional string will work as expected.

`NSString *someString = @"123456789012345678";
    NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-30s%@", [someString UTF8String], someString];
    NSLog(@"%@", someString);
    NSLog(@"%@", padded);`

Comment: @cnotethegr8 that only works for strings that happen to contain only  7-bit ASCII characters. The %s modifier does not expect UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 5):

2nd column of *what* would line up?

Given that you are on iOS, using HTML or a table view would be far more straightforward than trying to line up characters with spaces.  Beyond being programmatically more elegant, it will look better, be more resilient to input data changes over time, and render a user experience more in line with expectations for the platform.

If you *really* want to use spaces, then you are going to have to limit your UI to a monospace font (ugly for readability purposes outside of specific contexts, like source code) and international characters are going to be a bit of a pain.

From there, it would be a matter of getting the string length (keeping in mind that "length" does not necessarily mean "# of characters" in some languages), doing a bit of math, using `substringWithRange:` and appending spaces to the result.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Objective-C does not allow format specifiers for %@. A work-around for padding is the following:

```
NSString *padded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%*s", someString, 12-someString.length, ""];
```

which will pad the string to the right with spaces up to a field length of 12 characters.

Comment: This method works great. `%-10s` and `-UTFString` only works for ASCII strings. When it encounters CJK, or other unicode chars, it will be strange.

Answer (score 0):

%-@ does not work, but %-s works

```
NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3@", @"a" ];
NSString *y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3@", @"abcd" ];
NSString *z = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3@ %@", @"a", @"bc" ];
NSString *zz = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3s %@", "a", @"bc" ];
NSLog(@"[%@][%@][%@][%@].......", x,y,z,zz);
```

output:
    [a][abcd][a bc][a   bc].......

Answer (score 0):

Try below. its working for me.

```
NSString *someString = @"1234";
NSString *padded = [someString stringByPaddingToLength: 16 withString: @"x" startingAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", someString);
NSLog(@"%@", padded);
```

Answer (score -1):

First up, you're doing this a bad way. Please use separate labels for your two columns and then you will also be able to use proportional fonts. The way you're going about it you should be looking for an iPhone curses library.

If you really have to do it this way just use stringWithFormat:, like:

```
NSString *secondColumnString = @"xxx";
NSString *spacedOutString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testingColOne  %@", secondColumnString];
NSString *spacedOutString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testingAgain   %@", secondColumnString];
```

Comment: Your answer was fine up until adding the code.  That doesn't solve OP's specific problem....

Comment: How doesn't it right-pad the string? If you printed the two contents of spacedOutString one after the other they would align.

Comment: Because (a) his strings are variable length, thus, hardcoded spacings ain't gonna work and (b) he needs to truncate the strings, too.

Comment: Disagree, hardcoded spacing is what the question is all about - "right padded to a column width of say 12"

Comment: You're on the right track though; +stringWithFormat: is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Adam: the spacing (e.g. 12) is hard-coded, but the length of the text in column 1 isn't. So your technique won't solve this particular problem.