# Flexible spaces between strings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In my application, I want to create a **Receipt Layout** for printing. I'm struggling to create proper alignment between strings.

I want to create something like this (with proper alignments)

```
Coke         2       comment1
Chocolate    3       comment2
ice          4       comment3
```

Currently I have done like this

```
NSMutableString* strBody = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i=0; i<[arrItems count];i++){
    [strBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@           %@  %@",[[arrItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ProductName"],[[arrItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ProductQuantity"],[[arrItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Comment"]]];
}
```

But, here I just use **fixed length spaces**, so the issue is I'm not getting proper alignment. Currently what I am struggling is **how to put flexible spaces between string items**?

If anyone had do something like this, please give me some help.

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective-c code to right pad a NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386351/objective-c-code-to-right-pad-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate `UILabel` and use `setFrame` property to align all the labels....

or use **`\t`** (tab character depending on length of the string....

Comment: welcome... but some time \t will create problem when strings are too short or too long.... keep in mind that...