# NSString stringwithformat: Padding 2 strings with unknown length

Tags: ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

I'm having a problem doing something with NSString stringWithFormat...

The problem is as follows:

First of all, I have 2 strings. Which are money quantities.

The thing, is that i want to create 1 string with these two.

For ex:

```
strF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First: %@   Second: %@", value1, value2];
```

I want to know if there is possible to make a correct padding between First and Second.. Assuming the first string is not the same length always..

I want to make this:

```
First: 10,000.00         Second: 788.00
First: 10.00             Second: 788.00
First: 0.00              Second: 788.00
First: 100.00            Second: 788.00
First: 5.00              Second: 788.00
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386351/objective-c-code-to-right-pad-a-nsstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**revision** Here's a better way, using NSNumberFormatter:

First create and configure your formatter like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ] ;
[ formatter setFormatWidth:20 ] ;
[ formatter setPaddingCharacter:@" " ] ;
[ formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ] ;
[ formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle ] ;
[ formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2 ] ;
[ formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2 ] ;
```

Once you have created your formatter, your code becomes:

```
strF = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"First: %@ Second: %@", [ formatter stringFromNumber:value1 ], [ formatter stringFromNumber:value2 ] ] ;
```

You'll get the (thousands) separators (in the current locale) etc.

I would create the formatter in a class method (something like `+numberFormatter` or in a `dispatch_once` block) You could even add it to NSNumberFormatter via a category and have something like `+[ NSNumberFormatter mySharedFormatter ]`

---

You can use the field width specifier. It does this:

```
NSString * value1String = ... from NSNumberFormatter to get commas inserted ;
[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"First: %20s Second: %0.2f", [ value1String UTF8String ], value2 ]
```

Where "20" is the width of the column. (Replace by desired width). There's other options, like right justify, etc. Do `man printf` for more.

If you want to add the commas, NSNumberFormatter should be able to do that.

(Actually, you probably want your decimals to line up too, right? You could try `% 20.2f`)

Comment: The document says that `%s` will interpret the string in the system default encoding, so this is not really safe. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It worked.. but in the end.. Client asked for custom cell.. So... Meh!...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to set a maximum length of `value1` at least, and then you can do something like

```
int maxLength = MAX(15, value1.length); // Prevent cropping anyway
NSString* formattedValue1 = [value1 stringByPaddingToLength:maxLength withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0]
strF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First: %@ Second: %@", formattedValue1, value2];
```