# A format specifier such as `%15@` works in NSLog but not with NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, nslog, format-specifiers, stringwithformat

I found something strange when trying to use width specifiers with `%@`. They work fine in `NSLog` but not with `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Example:

```
NSString *rightAligned = @"foo";
NSString *leftAligned = @"1";

NSLog(@"| %15@ | %-15@ |", rightAligned, leftAligned);
```

And you get the expected output of:

```
|             foo | 1               |
```

But replace the `NSLog` with `stringWithFormat:`:

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"| %15@ | %-15@ |", rightAligned, leftAligned];
```

And the value of `test` is incorrectly:

```
| foo | 1 |
```

If I change this to use `%s` and `cStringUsingEncoding:` then it works:

```
NSString *test2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"| %15s | %-15s |", [rightAligned cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [leftAligned cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The result is the same as with `NSLog`.

What makes this really strange is that `NSLog` is basically just a wrapper around `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

So why the different results? Why aren't format specifiers honored for `%@` in `stringWithFormat` but they are with `NSLog`?

As a side note, the Swift `String init(format:)` initializer has the same problem with `%@` and width specifiers.

Comment: "NSLog is now just a shim to os_log in most circumstances." source: [Foundation Release Notes for macOS 10.12 and iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The mystery is why `%15@` would *ever* work. It should not.

Format specifiers come from `sprintf` which has no `%@` (it is just a special extension for Objective-C). As far as `stringWithFormat` goes, `%15s` has *always* been the way to say this; I can cite Stack Overflow examples such as [NSString stringwithformat: Padding 2 strings with unknown length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967558/nsstring-stringwithformat-padding-2-strings-with-unknown-length).

I'm guessing it only "works" because it now uses `os_log` under the hood; unfortunately, the `os_log` syntax is almost completely undocumented.

Comment: I suspect that if you try this with a sufficiently old version of Xcode, you'll find that NSLog matches `stringWithFormat` behavior.

Comment: I understand why `%15s` works. The question is asking why `%15@` works in `NSLog` but not `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: "The question is asking why %15@ works in NSLog" Yes, and I'm saying "I don't know because it shouldn't." :) I'm guessing it's because it now uses `os_log` under the hood; unfortunate the `os_log` syntax is almost completely undocumented.