# Objective-C: What is %-2i in NSLog?

Tags: objective-c

I am reading through a book on Objective-C and came by the following without any explanation:

```
NSLog(@"%-2i %i", n1, n2);
```

What does %-2i mean it just prints out the number the same way %i does?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for NSLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it left-aligns the first integer to 2 characters, a better answer is here:

[objective-c code to right pad a NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386351/objective-c-code-to-right-pad-a-nsstring)

Answer (score 2):

`NSLog()` and `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` use `printf(3)` formatting rules and from the [printf manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html):

> A negative field width flag; the converted value is to be left
>   adjusted on the field boundary.  Except for n conversions, the
>   converted value is padded on the right with blanks, rather than on the
>   left with blanks or zeros.  A - overrides a 0 if both are given.

So it prints the integer using 2 spaces which are left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question is usually frowned upon, as it's a simple thing to look up in the documentation, but let me add the relevant links:

Search for NSlog on google lets us to this page of the apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html

which tell us something about a "formatted string" and a `@"format"` (Saddly no direct link).
But when you plug that into the search bar at the top, you eventually get to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html. Again, it does not list the `%i`, but tells you to look at the IEEE fprintf documentation: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html.

And there finally, you find both the definition of the `%i` and the `-2i`:

> A negative field width is taken as a '-' flag followed by a positive field width. A negative precision is taken as if the precision were omitted

Comment: Sorry I would not have known what to look up but thank you for the links I really appreciate it.